# How to read a single character from very large file in Java

Tags: randomaccessfile

I am looking for the best efficient way to read only single character from very large file having size > 5GB. I came across several solutions like
- Using RandomAccessFile to create [indexed-file-reader](https://github.com/jramoyo/indexed-file-reader)
- Using Java 8 streams API
- Using BufferedReader/InputStreamReader

I just want to read a single character and would like to reduce Memory and I/O overhead as much as possible. 
I was wondering if is there any better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need that `RandomAccessFile` doesn't offer out of the box (viz., seek to any position and read one byte)?

Comment: I am just looking for better solution if is there any?

Comment: I need to read a character from large file may be more than 1 million times in my application. I am looking for solution which is memory and I/O efficient.

Comment: You'd have to explain more about how you choose which character to read each time. Perhaps there are patterns of access that could be exploited, or a different file structure that would be more efficient, or ancillary indexes that could be constructed to help. But knowing only that you need to read single bytes from locations randomly distributed through the file, `RandomAccessFile` is the simplest and most efficient thing to use.

Comment: Thanks @erickson for your comment. The input file has two columns separated by tab (it is txt file). Col1 contains some id and col2 contains DNA sequence. I want to fetch a character for given id at given position from large file. I am looking for the best and most efficient solution to perform this task.